# I am using Material Components which have MDCButton. I am trying to change color of that ButtonThemer

Tags: swift

```
{
   import MaterialComponents.MaterialButtons_ButtonThemer

   let buttonScheme = MDCButtonScheme()
   MDCContainedButtonThemer.applyScheme(buttonScheme, to: car_Button)
}
```

The code works fine, but the button colour is like this:
[image]

I want to change the button colour to this:
[[image]]

How can I do that?

Comment: @IBOutlet weak var car_Button : MDCButton!

Comment: UIColor *inkColor I try with ink colour too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Change the button colour using the MDCColorScheming.

```
buttonScheme.colorScheme = Your colour scheme(MDCColorScheming)
```

You can check the link to get a better understanding of **[MDCColorScheming](https://material.io/develop/ios/components/theming/color/)**